# How to capture iPhone screen with animating UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, screenshot, screen-capture

I have a UIImageView placed over a view and I want to capture iPhone screen while that UIImageView is animating.

I can successfully capture the screen shots of the still frames of the UIImageView like this:

```
[[myView layer] renderInContext:context];
```

However when the UIImageView is animating throguh

`[MyImageView startAnimating]`

then, those animating frames are not captured.

Is there any alternative to renderInContext available at the moment that can capture the animating frames as well?

NOTE: I know UIGetScreenImage() is no longer accepted by Apple after iOS4 update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CALayers use a presentationLayer to represent the current state of the layer while animating. `CALayer`'s `-presentationLayer` method returns you the presentation layer. So you might want to try `[[[myView layer] presentationLayer] renderInContext:context];` to capture its contents.